# Keep SensorEventListener during "standby"

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, wakelock, standby

I'm building an app that needs to listen to the accelerometer all the time, even when the application is not in foreground.
(At this point, I want to clarify that this is not an app for Play Store. This is an app with a specific purpose for internal usage where battery drain is not much of a problem - Also, if anyone knows another way to check if the user is walking, please let me know either)

To achieve this, I created a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and starts a service that registers the `SensorEventListener`. The service acquires a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` and I was hoping that with this lock the `SensorEventListener` would still receive the `onChange()` callback, but that is not happening. However, with the `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` it works - but i do not want to keep the screen on and the user may also press the standby button...
In my debug sessions, I never saw the service being destroyed, therefore, the wake lock should never be released.

Here's the `Service` class that acquires the lock and registers the sensor:

```
public class WalkingDetectorService extends Service {

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    private static final String LOCK_TAG = "WALKING_DETECTOR";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        acquireLock(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // started on boot from a BroadcastReceiver
        startMotionDetector(getApplication());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        releaseLock();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startMotionDetector(Application application) {

        int sensitivityIdx = SettingsManager.getInt(application, SettingsManager.SETTING_SENSOR_SENSITIVITY);

        if (sensitivityIdx == -1) {
            sensitivityIdx = MotionSensor.DEFAULT_SENSITITY_IDX;
        }

        float fSens = MotionSensor.getSensivity(sensitivityIdx);

        //SensorEventListener is registered here. It is properly done. Only stops listen when screen goes off (by timeout or user pressing the standby button)
            MotionSensor.startMotionSensor(application, fSens);

    }

    public static synchronized void acquireLock(Context ctx) {
        if (wakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, LOCK_TAG);
            wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static synchronized void releaseLock() {
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            if (wakeLock.isHeld())
            {
                wakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I provided all the information needed to get some help from you.
If you feel like there's some piece of code that would be useful, I'll be happy to colaborate! Thank you